# Elmah doesn't work on the server

Tags: asp.net, elmah

Elmah appears to work on my dev machine but on the server I can request elmah.axd fine but it doesn't log any exceptions. There are no error messages and there is no feed back it *just doesn't work* (which ought to be the slogan for a rubbish software company)

Here are selected highlights from my web.config file:

```
    <elmah>
 <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/errors" />

    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
  </elmah>
<location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>


        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>

     <httpModules>
             <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
        </httpModules>

    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
<modules>
             <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
</modules>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In my case it was because of the missing write permissions on the App_Data directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending bit of config is I think...

```
<location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

When I installed Elmah Nuget made a bit of a mess of web.config. It added unnecessary and corrupting `xmlns=""`s and added additional `system.webserver` and `system.web` sections which aren't allowed.

Something must have confused it which resulted in this location tag being added that I'm guessing resulted in the modules/handlers being given too narrow a scope to catch all errors.

I don't have any idea why this worked locally but not remotely. Maybe because my remote deploy is in a virtual directory?